# Circuit for LED and motor

Tags: led, motor, resistors, coin-cell

I'm building a vibrating dog that lights up for my friend's birthday. I've designed this circuit, but I'm not sure if it's the best way to do things. Specifically, I don't know if there is enough current to drive the motor. Here is the circuit:

---

[image]

Comment: 980 uA to run the motor!!?  That sounds very very low unless this is maybe a MEMS motor.  Even cell phone vibrator motors, which don't really have any load, take 10s of mA at 3 V.

Comment: Apologies, it was supposed to be 0.98A. I'll change it.

Comment: 980 mA from a CR2032 coin cell is absolutely positivively no way gonna happen.  Not even close.

Answer (score 7):

It won't work for a couple of reasons:

- The CR2032 will not supply anywhere near 980mA. See a typical [2032 datasheet](http://www.maxell.co.jp/e/products/industrial/battery/cr/pdf/CR2032_DataSheet_e.pdf) (and another [here](http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/cr2032.pdf)), note the nomimnal discharge is 0.2mA and internal resistance is between 10 and 40Ω.
- If you do have a suitable battery, then without the resistor the LED will blow as it can only handle a maximum of 20mA. In series circuits all the components will share the same current, so whatever goes through the motor goes through the LED. With the resistor there will not be enough current to power the motor (there will only be around 10mA available)

So, you need a different battery capable of supplying 1.5V - 3V @ 980mA (note that you will need over 2V for the LED drop of ~2V, so at least 2.4V is preferable) A couple of AAs should work for brief motor use. Battery quality varies, and current capability also, so check the datasheet of whatever battery you use to make sure it's suitable.

Also, you need to have the LED and a resistor in parallel with the motor. Something like the circuit below:

[image: Circuit]

Answer (score 1):

This will not work.

The current through a series circuit will be the same everywhere. Your LED needs 20mA, the motor 0.98. That means either the motor will not work or the LED will die.

What you need is a parallel circuit to drive 20mA through the LED and 0.98A through the motor. But I don't think the motor will be strong enough to handle physical difficulties in your dog. Also, the button cell's life won't last very long.

Comment: The OP has now changed the required motor current by 1000x.  Your conclusion is still right in that it won't work, but now it's the LED that will die if you run the motor as intended.